# Can’t Make Only One .children( ) Show Up When Using the onkeyup Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Long time reader, first time poster. I’ve tried looking for an answer everywhere. I’m really stuck. 
I have a form with two label tags, each containing an input and a select tag:

```
    <body>
  <form action="Page_Form.php" method="post">                  
<label class="try">Main Product:  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="main_product" id="main_product" maxlength="30" onkeyup="getNames(this.value)"/> 
<select  multiple="multiple" class="results" id="results" onchange="displayResult(this)"><option></option></select></label>
<label class="try">Secondary Product: <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="secondary_product" id="secondary_product" maxlength="30" onkeyup="getNames(this.value)"/>
<select  multiple="multiple" class="results" id="results" onchange="displayResult(this)"><option></option></select>
</label>

</form>
</body>
```

When the user writes something, the  tag with the class ".results" shows up, using the onkeyup event. Here's my JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function getNames(value) {
      if(value != "") {$("label").children(".results",$(this)).show();} else {$("label").children(".results",$(this)).hide();} 

}
function resultsHide() {
{$(".results").hide();};
}
window.onload = resultsHide;

</script>
```

The problem is, both of the select tags show up simultaneously, **and I want only the direct child select tag of the label tag to show up**.

I’ve tried using .children() and. find (), in any variation I could think of. 
Is there a way to make only the direct child show up? 
Here is a [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BobyTaylor/xNu53/20/).
Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the `onkeypress` attributes from the elements and do the binding through jquery, so `this` will actually point to the element.

also add a common class to the elements you want to have the same behavior (*i used class `products`*), like this

```
<input type="text" class="product" autocomplete="off" name="main_product" id="main_product" maxlength="30"/>
```

Try this code instead

```
$(function(){
    $('.product').on('keyup', getNames);
});

function getNames() {
    var value = this.value,
        results = $(this).siblings('.results');
    if (value != "") {
        results.show();
    } else {
        results.hide();
    }
}
```

The idea is to start traversing the DOM from the element you already have (*the `input` in this case*) towards the element you want (*since they are related*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/xNu53/25/

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between the two selects when showing/hiding. 
Something like this:

```
  if($(product).hasClass("main")) {
      $("label").children(".results.main",$(this)).show();
  } 
  else {$("label").children(".results.main",$(this)).hide();}
```

Take a look at this modified version.

http://jsfiddle.net/xNu53/33/